# Encontrar descripción del servicio (WSDL) para esta url

Tags: soap, wsdl

Estoy tratando de consumir algunos servicios SOAP. Entre ellos esta esta url:

`https://api.service.gnp.com.mx/autos/wsp/catalogos/catalogo`

Mi problema reside en que no puedo encontrar la descripción del servicio. No soy muy conocedor del tema, pero investigando me encontrado que se podría acceder de esta manera:

`https://api.service.gnp.com.mx/autos/wsp/catalogos/catalogo.asmx?wsdl`

Ó también de esta otra manera:

`https://api.service.gnp.com.mx/autos/wsp/catalogos/catalogo?wsdl`

Pero no he obtenido resultados. ¿Hay alguna manera de escanear estos servicios y obtener el WSDL? Con otros servicios similares al obtener WSDL importo a postman la api y de ahí puedo generar el código que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Si no está devolviendo la descripción del contrato puede ser que la url esta errónea o el servicio tenga algún inconveniente.